# What is the effect of taking the mean of a moments-based estimate?

Tags: estimation, mean, moments

Suppose I estimate the second and fourth moments of a signal as

$M_2 \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} | y_n |^2$

and

$M_4 \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} | y_n |^4$

and then I use these to estimate the SNR of a signal. For example, Pauluzzi and Beaulieu <sup>1</sup> describe an estimator for an M-ary PSK signal with complex noise:

$\rho = \frac{\sqrt{2 M_2^2 - M_4}}{M_2 - \sqrt{2 M_2^2 - M_4}}$

What would be the effect of taking, say, $N'$ estimates of $\rho$ and computing the mean of these estimates, versus just using $N\times N'$ samples to estimate $M_2$ and $M_4$ in the first place?

My intuition says that the latter is more meaningful, but I can't figure out how to explain why.

<sup>1</sup> Pauluzzi, D.R.; Beaulieu, N.C., "A comparison of SNR estimation techniques for the AWGN channel," in Communications, IEEE Transactions on , vol.48, no.10, pp.1681-1691, Oct 2000
doi: 10.1109/26.871393 ([Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/871393))

Comment: This will often give very imprecise estimates. You should look into Lmoments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, it's better to use a single estimator that incorporates all the rather than the average of several estimators that uses subsets of the data (side note: bagging *could* be thought of as an alternative, but that's really a special case).

Here's a common example of why you would want pool all your data rather than just using the average of stratified estimators, which I believe applies to your case (although not the only reason). Many estimators are biased but consistent; I'm fairly certain your case is an example of that. Suppose we can then write the following about the expected value:

$\mathbb{E}[\hat \theta] = \theta g(n) $,

with  $|g(n) - 1| > |g(n+1)-1|$

and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}g(n) = 1$

(Note: there's cases of consistent estimators that don't meet this criteria, but there are plenty more that do. And I do believe that your estimator fits this criteria).

Suppose then we have $\hat \theta_1$ and $\hat \theta_2$, where these are estimators used from cutting our data in half and separately estimating $\theta$ from each data set. Meanwhile, $\hat \theta_.$ is the estimator created from using all the data.

Then we get that

$\mathbb{E}[ (\hat \theta_1 + \hat \theta_2)/2] = (\theta g(n/2) + \theta  g(n/2) )/2 =\theta g(n/2)$

While on the other hand

$\mathbb{E}[ (\hat \theta_.) ] = \theta g(n)$,

Since $|1 - g(n)|$ < $|1 - g(n/2)$|,

this implies that $\hat \theta_.$ is less biased than $(\hat \theta_1 + \hat \theta_2)/2$

More generally, many estimators have nice *asymptotic* properties. By cutting up your full sample into smaller samples and averaging across, you may be reducing the asymptotic effect.